# Android Eclipse: .gitignore not ignoring bin and gen directories at all

Tags: android, eclipse, git, github, gitignore

I am trying to ignore some eclipse generated files that are not relevant for a push and here is my folder structure:

```
Project1/
   .gitignore
   extras/
      ..some stuff here
   Project1/
      bin
      gen
      libs
      res
      ..and so forth
```

so I need the inner Project1 that is inside of outer Project1 because Eclipse was getting all crazy for not having a folder structure like that and it wouldn't import my project so that's that. The git ignore seems to work for the extras folder but not for bin, and gen or anyhting inside inner Project1 folder. I tried adding the folder like Project1/bin  but nothing was hapening and git stil notices changes.

Here is my file:

```
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin
gen
extras

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project
project.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Intellij project files
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/
```

This is my first android github project so I am still learning. Please do not mind if my questions or  assumptions are wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am stuck at this too.

Comment: @AjayGautam, unfortunately no. I switched to Android Studio so that fixed the problem..

Comment: Answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850678/eclipse-git-gitignore-file-is-ignored

Comment: @AjayGautam, that was the solution. I needed to remove the folder/item from git's cache, since I had the folder already on my repo. If it is a pre gitignore folder/file it needs to be removed from cache. If you added something to gitignore and you have not ever pushed that thing to git, then it should automatically ignore it, since it has not been cached yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `bin` to `Project1\bin\**`, and similarly `gen` to `Project1\gen\**`.

Comment: Yeah I tried it and it is not working at all.

Comment: That is weird. Your .git folder is in the outer Project1 directory right?

Comment: yes the outermost. where it is along with the extras folder and inner project1 folder

Comment: Just noticed that you don't have a / infront of bin or gen. Use bin/ and gen/

Comment: not working again...I have no idea why...

Comment: Check your gitignore configurations again. If you have the latest version of git, then bin/ should work :). Worst case, restructuring your project might not be a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will definitely try to update my git. The only problem is that I can't restructure my project due to Eclipse's weird structure problem.