# git is not ignoring an eclipse .version file

Tags: eclipse, git, gitignore

It may be something simple, but I cannot make git ignore this. I have put different combinations of things into the .gitignore file in the directory at the root of my repository.

But I still see:

```
 $ git status
 On branch master
 Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

  Changes not staged for commit:
    (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
    (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore
    modified:   MyProject/build/.version

 no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
 $
```

I have "build" in my .gitignore file. I have tried "MyProject/build/.version", "build/.version", ".version" and various combinations thereof. But perhaps not the right combination.

Comment: Duplicate of e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850678/eclipse-git-gitignore-file-is-ignored, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038600/gitignore-not-ignoring-web-config, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716553/gitignore-not-ignoring-file.

Answer (score 2):

If you've only just added `build` to your `.gitignore`, then the files which were tracked before will still be tracked. `.gitignore` only prevents git from tracking *new, untracked* files which match the pattern given. To remove the file from git's history, without removing the file locally, you can run

```
git rm -r --cached build
```

to remove everything in the build directory, or

```
git rm --cached MyProject/build/.version
```

(or whatever the path is) to just remove the one file.

Answer (score 1):

Try entering the following in your .gitignore:

```
/build
```

Another thing to try is

```
build/
```